# If you have $t$ sets of the form$\{0,1,⋯k\}$, is the number of ways that you can sum an element from each set that adds up to $k$ smaller than $t^k$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that I have a product of $t$ exponentials of the form $e^{A_1x} \cdots e^{A_tx}$ , and I choose some $k > 1$. Consider the number of terms involving a power of $x^k$.

For instance if $t=2, k=2$, then 
$e^{A_1x}e^{A_2x} = (I+xA_1+x^2/2A_1+\cdots)(I+xA_2+x^2/2A_2+\cdots)$
=$ (I+xA_2 + x^2/2A_2 +xA_1+x^2A_1A_2+x^3/2A_1A_2+x^2/2A_1+x^3/2A_1A_2+x^4/4A_1A_2)$

has $3$ terms with a scalar multiple of $x^2$ (ignoring the multiplying factor of $1/2$). Now I notice that this number is smaller than $t^k = 4$.

I want to know if this bound is generally true?

It seems like this is essentially a combinatorial problem that if you have $t$ sets of the form $\{0,1, \cdots k\}$, is the number of ways that you can sum an element from each set that adds up to $k$ smaller than $t^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $k$ into $t$ terms.  You choose $t$ numbers that sum to $k$ to get the number of terms of the form $x^k$.  There are ${k+t-1 \choose t-1}=\frac{(k+t-1)!}{(t-1)!k!}$ of them.  This is generally tiny compared to $t^k$.  For $t=1$ there is just one choice, so it equals $t^k$.  For $t=2$ it is $k+1$ because you can choose any number for the first summand and then the second is fixed.  This is much smaller than $2^k$ unless $k=1$ where it is equal.  For $t=3$ it is $\frac 12k(k+1)$ which is less than $3^k$ and so on.  I don't have a general proof.